# If I have the vector `2, 7, 12`, how can I create the vector `2, 2+1, 2+2, 7, 7+1, 7+2, 12, 12+1, 12+2`?

Tags: r, vector

If I have next vector:

```
vector <- c(1,6,10)
```

How can I create the vector `1 2 3 6 7 8 10 11 12`?

Another example:

```
vector <- c(4,9,15)
```

My desired vector would be `4 5 6 9 10 11 15 16 17`.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can do

```
c( sapply(vector, function(x) x:(x + 2)))
```

---

Or with

```
sort(vector + rep(0:2, each = length(vector)))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `outer` :

```
vector <- c(1,6,10)
c(t(outer(vector, 0:2, `+`)))
#[1]  1  2  3  6  7  8 10 11 12
```